Error - CQL/Metadata and 'host.is_up' with None/Null value (differences with nodetool)
It seems as bug in python cassandra-driver for Apache Cassandra, please correct me, If I am wrong.
I connected to the Apache Cassandra cluster (I tested Cassandra in the last versions 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 with the python client cassandra-driver 3.29.2 from DataStax). I used for checking the node state, this part of code (I used CQL not nodetool, because I am out of privileges and access to different port than 9042):
...
metadata = self._cluster.metadata

for host in metadata.all_hosts():
    host_info = {
        'address': host.address,
        'data_center':host.datacenter,
        'rack': host.rack,
        'release_version': host.release_version,
        'is_up': host.is_up,
    } 
...

I got for all nodes from first data center correct values host.is_up with value True, but I got None (Null) values for other nodes from secondary data center.
NOTE: The information from nodetool status are, that all nodes (cross two data centers) have the stat UN (Up and Normal).
Did you solve the same issue?
